# How to break a line in blade templete on laravel insted of <br>

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade

I can not break line in Blade templete on laravel framework .
Please help me to print each element in one line . Code is given below

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    The current value is {{$i}}

@endfor
```

Comment: I think you have to use `<br/>`. You can try `{{ $i."\n" }}`, but I'm pretty sure that won't work...

Comment: Do not work However Thanks

Comment: cross-platform-compatible way too `{{ $i . PHP_EOL }}`

Answer (score 0):

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    The current value is {{$i}}
    <br>
@endfor
```

or:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    <p>The current value is {{$i}}</p>
@endfor
```

or:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    <div>The current value is {{$i}}</div>
@endfor
```

or:

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    The current value is {{$i}}
    <hr>
@endfor
```